# Alerta basada en comparativa de dos columnas (función ui)

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy intentando hacer un código para que al comparar los valores de dos columnas indique si los Valores son Incorrectos en base a una condición.

El problema es que al poner el rango de las columnas (F:F y H:H) a comparar no funciona, hice la prueba poniendo celdas especificas (F7 y H7) y de esta forma sí envía el mensaje.

¿Se requiere hacer algo adicional?

Nota: para que se muestre el mensaje use un activador por edición.

```
function ValidateData() {
  // Validar Valores
  var V1Range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base de Datos").getRange("F:F");
  var V2Range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base de Datos").getRange("H:H");
  var V1Value = CpPpRange.getValue();
  var V2Value = CpkPpkRange.getValue();
  
    // Hacer validación y Enviar Alerta
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if (V1Value > V2Value){
    ui.alert('Valores Incorrectos');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getValue()` devuelve el valor o objeto tipo Date de la celda superior izquierda. Si tu quieres obtener todos los valores del rango, en su lugar debes usar `getValues()`. Este método te devolverá un Array que incluirá un Array por cada fila del rango el cual a su vez incluirá un valor u objeto tipo Date por cada celda de la fila correspondiente.

Sobre la comparación  del Array de una columna con el correspondiente a la otra faltaría tener claro si deseas hacer la comparación de una fila a fila o si debe realizarse de otra manera. En cualquier caso te resultarán muy útiles los métodos de `Array.prototype` como `reduce`, `map`, `every`, `some`, etc.